# Choosing two numbers, one with a broad range... spin buttons?

Tags: buttons, winforms, spinner, range

Re-designing a GUI for setting properties like frequency channel numbers, I want to let users choose two numbers. The first one ranges from 800 to 805 but the second one ranges from 00 to 99.

[image: channel number field]

On the current GUI there are 106 buttons. Was thinking of using a spin button for each range, but now I think that a spin button ranging from 00 to 99 is too annoying to use.

Any other ideas?

(BTW, for context: The GUI is in WindowsForms and the station a mouse-operated Windows 7, used by untrained workers. The field with the channel numbers is used several hundred times a day.)

Comment: By mouse-operated, do you mean no keyboard?

Comment: Yes. Most stations have no keyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the fact that the keyboard isn't an option, I would leave all the channels visible as they are now. Hiding them into a scrollable dropdown-menu/spinner will increase the interactions and the time needed to search, find and select a number.

I strongly suggest you to change the layout of the matrix to 10*10 instead of the current 20*5: a layout coherent with the rules of our decimal system would respect and take advantage of the users' mental models.
This alone would improve the workflow quite a lot.

I also see that you have a Set button: if this command is very repetitive and gets used hundreds of times during the day, I would make the setting automatic when choosing a frequency to avoid another step and make the workflow smoother.

In any case I would recommend to prototype different versions and to test them with the final users to see which one suits better their needs if you can.

Answer (score 2):

*Typing is the fastest way to enter the information.*

There is nothing wrong with letting the user type in the values, provided you have appropriate validation on the field.

(If the value being entered was something approximate, I might have suggested a slider, but that would be too fiddly for selecting precise values such as frequencies.)